# PHP mail function 'from' address

Tags: email, php

I'm not even sure this is possible, however what I'm trying to do is as follows. I have an HTML form that generates and email using a `PHP` script. What I want is to recieve emails from this form to `abc@xyz.com`, then I want the `from` address to appear as one of the fields in the form.

I have had a look around and found some useful information on this [site](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp). I'm not sure whether `sendmail_from` can be used in this situation, or if it does what I'm asking.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See this page on the same site (example 2): http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

You will have to set the headers of the message to include the From and other stuff like CC or BCC:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Note that you have to separate the headers with a newline sequence `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Just a note if it is a dynamic field from a form just replace webmaster@example.com with a `$variable` also you can use this format also `$username<$email>`.

Comment: I'd of included the official manual on PHP's `mail()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php also/instead.

Answer (score 4):

For a php mail script I have used this for contact forms:

```
$from = $_POST["from"];  //posted from the form.

mail("me@myname.com", $subject, $message, "From:" . $from);
```

I have not used a sendmail_from in my php before, only a simple variable.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You really should sanitize that $_POST["from"] variable before pass it to the mail() function. A malicious user could inject any number of other headers using your method.

Comment: Furthermore it will most likely end up in the spam folder on most mail servers systems since `From` does not match the sending domain. I would leave `From` set to a local email on the server and instead set a sanitized `Reply-To` header.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you cant do it in the email headers?

```
$to      = 'hello@hello.com';
$subject = 'my subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from_form. "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```