# PHP MAILER: Root User replace From Information

Tags: php, email, root, mailer

This event happens so randomly and I have no clue as to why. Information that appears looks like this.

```
From: Root User < root@localhost.mydomain.com >
```

Below is a snippet of what I wrote:

```
    $frtname = (!empty($_POST['frtname'])? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['frtname']) :null);
    $lstname = (!empty($_POST['lstname'])? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lstname']) :null);
    $email   = (!empty($_POST['email'])? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) :null);



    $message=$body;

    $new_recipient = array(
          'user@email.com' => 'User Name',
          'user1@email.com' => 'User Name 1'
    );


    require_once ('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
     try{ 
          $mail = new PHPMailer();
          $mail->SetLanguage("en",'phpMailer/language/');
          $mail->Priority              = 1;

          $mail->SetFrom(stripcslashes($email), stripcslashes($frtname." ".$lstname), true);
          $mail->AddReplyTo(stripcslashes($email), stripcslashes($frtname." ".$lstname)); 

          foreach($new_recipient as $email => $name){
               $email      = str_replace("'", "", $email);
               $name      = str_replace("'", "", $name);

               $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
          }

          $mail->Subject = stripcslashes($subject);

          $mail->MsgHTML(stripcslashes($message));

          $mail->AltBody = 'This email is best view as HTML format.';


           if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           } else {
                 echo "Message sent!";
                 $message="Your information was received, click ok to continue";
           }

           $mail->ClearAddresses();
           $mail->ClearAttachments();

      }catch(phpmailerException $e){
           echo $e->errorMessage();
           $message = "Your message was not sent. Please try again.";
      }catch(Exception $e){
           echo $e->getMessage();
           exit;
      }
```

I am already using a try and catch method here. Can anyone give an insight as to why this is happening? Do i give up on phpMailer?

Comment: *Where* do you see this? Please show your code, as now it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mail function 'from' address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741165/php-mail-function-from-address)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179014/how-to-change-envelope-from-address-using-php-mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure and set the Sender property, as well as the From and FromName properties.  Also, when you do that, make sure it's an email address for a valid domain, with an MX and SPF record.

If the Sender property isn't set, sendmail will inject the header with the default info for the server, usually something like nobody@myserver.com or root@myserver.com

Comment: I used `SetFrom` which i saw would accept both name and email

Comment: OK.  You still need to set the Sender property.  It's separate from the From and FromName properties, and is important to ensure deliverability.